# Указатель не изменил содержащую в себе ссылку

Tags: c++

После вывода в консоль, получаю результат `4`.

Как такое может быть?

```
void f(int* p)
{
   int a = 47;
   p = &a;
}

int main()
{
   int* p = new int(4);

   f(p);

   std::cout << *p << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: передайте указатель по ссыльке

Comment: @ArHovsepyan это я понимаю. мне не нужно изменить значение. я хотел привести пример с тем, как можно получить не валидный указатель, но в итоге его адресс не изменился. почему?

Comment: Вы поменяли значение локальной переменной функции f, а у неё время жизни очень короткое.

Comment: Откройте ассемблерный код - будет понятно почему. Возможно оптимизатор нужно отключить. Только тогда... Если не сработает "защита" - вы получите ссылку на мусор.

Comment: @nick_n_a понял. но как можна отключить эту оптимизацю? как бы... здесь ожидается UB, а по факту мы получаем совсем не то, что надо.

Comment: Потому,что `*p` это новая переменная с указателем, а `*&p` - это ссылка на указатель в main. Так вам и предлагали сделать.

Comment: У вас НЕТ никакого UB.

Comment: @nick_n_a дефолтный компилятор VS 2019

Comment: @Mikhailo вы правы. Я забыл, да, переменная при функции считается локальной. Поэтому при изменении локальной, первоначальная (ту которую передали через вызов) не меняется. И с компилятором и опциями это не связано. Попробуйте так `void f(int*& p)`

Comment: @nick_n_a так работает, но тепер я понятия не имею, каким образом на нашем проекте образовывались мемори лики, через переприсваивание других адрессов указателям, которые были переданы в функцию, если делается копия этого указателя.так работало во всех стандартах языка?

Comment: Потренируйтесь с указателями. `p=..` - это присвоение значения локальной переменной. А `(*p)=..` это изменение значения области памяти по адресу `p`.

Comment: Запись `f(int*& p)` практически равносильна `f(int** p)` с разницей в том, что вам не прийдется вот так  `*p = &a;` писать, а это сделает компилятор. Ссылка - это как "неявный указатель". Ассемблерный код что через `f(int** p)` что через `f(int*& p)` будет собран одинаково.

Comment: @AlexGlebe я знаю, как работает разыменование :) спасибо. я хотел как раз изменить адрес.

Comment: @nick_n_a этот синтаксис похож на извращение немного, но спасибо. я понял свою ошибку. поработаю над этим.

Comment: Это не извращение, это разные вещи. `int` - это число. `int *` - указатель на число. `int * *` - указатель на ( указатель на число ). Вы хотели поменять указатель, по-этому вы должны были передавать именно так.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Переданный в функцию указатель "отрывается" от переменной в `main`.

То, что вы внутри сделали

```
p = &a;
```

это - изменение *локальной переменной* `p`. Которая *никак* не связана с тем, что хранится в переменной `p` в функции `main` - просто изначально она содержала то же значение.

Что еще хуже - в нее вы записали адрес локальной же переменной, так что *очень хорошо*, что он (указатель) не вышел за пределы функции, иначе бы вы получили UB - указатель на уничтоженную переменную `a` (это к данному в комментариях совету использовать ссылку на указатель).

Comment: Ребята, вы можете внимательно пожалуйста читать вопрос? 
Эту ситуацию я сделал специально, так как хотел получить UB. это первое. 
Второе, если я передаю аргумент функции как указатель, это никакая не локальная переменная, это тот же указатель.

Comment: @raviga Нет, у вас тут две локальные переменные, типом которых является указатель на int. Изменение значения одной из них никак не сказываются на второй.

Comment: Нет!! Вы передали ЗНАЧЕНИЕ `p` в функцию, а дельше - делается КОПИЯ. Ну, а почему выводится 4 - это так, мусор в выделенной памяти. Вы вообще не сделали ничего незаконного, просто бессмысленное. Ну как если бы написали `int n = 5; int m = n; m=6;` и ждали бы, что теперь `n` тоже должно быть 6.

Comment: @Mikhailo копия чего? Адресса указателя или того, что под тем адрессом содержится?

Comment: Содержится *копия* адреса переменной. (у вас же `int*`). Правильно писать или так `void  f(int** p)` или если не хочется лишний явный указатель то так `void f(int*& p)`

Comment: @Mikhailo я понял, спасибо. после нескольких лет работы, я узнаю это только сегодня. тогда получается, я был не прав.

Answer (score 2):

Поставьте код функции в точке вызова функции и получите такой код:

```
int* p = new int(4);
int* _p = p; 
int a = 47;
_p = &a; //теперь _p указывает на  а
std::cout << *p << std::endl;
//p по прежнему указывает на new int(4)
```